# Nginx HTTPS in 1 hostfile for all

Tags: nginx

I have multiple hostfiles. I also have a basic: "default" hostfile (with phpmyadmin locations etc)

In this file I would like to force a redirect to https for all other hostfiles. I'm not sure how to do this in the example below.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name signup.mysite.com; <-- this should be a wildcard
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> if

example:

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  test.com;
        if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
        }
        client_max_body_size   10M;
        client_body_buffer_size   128k;

        root       /home/test/test/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
               }
        }
```

and you can use it for multiply sites.

more info [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx) and [this](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know that the if statement would work on Nginx :-)